# How to get left align y axis value of bar chart in google api?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I referred this [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart)

for draw bar chart in google api. In this chart shown here

[image]

In this chart i get y axis value align from right side (marked in chart). 
but i need y axis value align from left side.

expect format y axis value displayed:

```
0-19

20-64

64+
```

Comment: Setting text alignment on the axis values is not supported in the API.  You can file feature request to add support for this [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list).

Comment: "y axis" is normally referred to as vAxis :)

Answer (score 4):

@asgallant is right, of course.

However, there is actually a workaround! Normally google visualization strips special characters such as `\n`, `\t` and so on, and will just render HTML-codes like `&nbsp;` as plain text. But unicode characters is rendered as they should.

So you can add the unicode character `\u00A0` (nonbreaking space) in the end of the values to fill the gaps, and by that you will get a left-aligned vAxis. To make it completely left-aligned visually, use a fixed-width font like monotype or courier.

```js
 var n, f, max = 4;
 for (var i=0;i<data.getNumberOfRows();i++) {
    n=data.getValue(i,0).toString();
    for (f=n.length;f<=max;f++) { n+='\u00A0'; }
    data.setValue(i,0,n);
  }
  var options = {
    vAxis : { 
       textStyle : { fontName: 'courier' }
      }
  };
```

see jsfiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/aB36z/**

[image]